# Как сделать ввод только русских букв и цифр на C#

Tags: c#

Читал форумы, чтобы сделать ввод в текстбокс только русских символов нужно написать следующее:

```
    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        char l = e.KeyChar;
        if (l = 1)
        if (l < 'А' || l > 'я')
        e.Handled = true ;
    }
```

Однако кроме русских букв мне нужен еще и ввод цифр, но как добавить исключение в e.KeyChar я не знаю(.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (!
    ((l >= 'А' && l <= 'я') 
    || (l >= '0' && l <= '9') 
    || l == 'ё' 
    || l == 'Ё' 
    || l == '\b')) {} // :)
```

Comment: Спасибо, а можно еще добавить backspace?